# JPA 2.0 Hibernate @OneToMany + @MapKeyJoinColumn

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

OneToMany + MapKeyJoinColumn doesn't work for me, please suggest what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using JPA 2.0 + Hibernate 3.6.1
And want to map following tables:

---

[image: Question to Statement to Language relationship]

---

To Classes:

---

```
@Entity
public class Question {
    // id and other fields

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="language_id")
    private Map<Language, Statement> statements =
        new HashMap<Language, Statement>();
}

@Entity
public class Statement {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "language_id", nullable = true)
    private Language language;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", nullable = false)
    private Question question;

    @Column(name = "message")
    private String message;
}

@Entity
public class Language {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
}
```

But it doesn't work. EntityManager persists it correctly, but when I retrieve Question, in it's statements map there is only one language-to-null entry.
Please, help

---

**Edit1**: Strange, but when I preload all Languages, like this:

```
String sql = "select l from Language l";
List languages = entityManager.createQuery(sql, Language.class).getResultList();
```

then it works!
**Does anybody know how to make hibernate automatically load all objects of certain class?**

Comment: Similar setup works fine for me. Can you show your testing code?

Comment: Do you use Hibernate 3.6.1 or something else?

Comment: I test it in the following way: insert some data manually to the database, then just call in junit test something like <code> entityManager.find(Question.class, 463L); </code>

Answer (score 3):

In fact, the id property in your class Statement must be a composite primary key. You do not need a statement_id in your table Statement. The primary key is composed of both language_id  and question_id.

Try that :

```
    @Entity
    public class Statement implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @EmbeddedId
        private StatementId id = new StatementId();

        @Column(name = "message")
        private String message;
    }

    @Embeddable
    private static class StatementId implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        StatementId(){}

        @ManyToOne
        private Question product;

        @ManyToOne
        private Language language;

    }
```

And do not forget the fetchType in Question in order to avoid
LazyInitializationExceptions.

```
public class Question {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="id.question", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyJoinColumn(name="language_id")
    private Map<Language, Statement> statements = new HashMap<Language, Statement>();
}
```

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using second-level caching? 
Is your object already part of the session (first-level caching)? Try doing a session clear()

Comment: No, I don't use second-level cache, the problem arise when there is nothing in session (just started), when there are no Language instances in the session.

Answer (score 1):

Try calling statements.size() to make sure the data are fetched or you could try defining the fetch type of your relationship to EAGER :   @OneToMany(mappedBy="question", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)

You might want to read this : http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Eager_Join_Fetching