# how to return Map<Key, Value> with HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

i have a table

**Permission**:

- id
- name
- desc

what i am doing right now
is to make a query that returns a permission object then put the values in the map programmatically

1- But i was wondering if it's possible to make an HQL (or native sql if not possible) to select the **permission_id**, **permission_name** and return them in a map.

2- is it possible to return map  in one to many relationship instead of following list or set

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "perm_cat_map", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "perm_cat_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id") })
    private List<Permission> permissions = new ArrayList<Permission>(0);
```

is it possible to have something like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "perm_cat_map", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "perm_cat_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id") })
        private Map<String,String> permissions = new ArrayList<String,String>(0);
```

where the two strings are **permission_id**, **permission_name**.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

1. Use the `select new map` syntax in HQL to fetch the results of each row in a `Map`. Take a look at the following question, that addresses the issue: [How to fetch hibernate query result as associative array of list or hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/q/925363/851811).
   For instance, the following HQL: `select new map(perm.id as pid, perm.name as pname) from Permission perm` will return a `List` of `Map`s, each one with keys "pid" and "pname".
2. It is not possible to map an association to a `Map<String, String>`. It is possible to map the key of the Map to a column with the [`@MapKeyColumn`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyColumn.html) annotation in the association. See this question, that also addresses the issue, for an example: [JPA 2.0 Hibernate @OneToMany + @MapKeyJoinColumn](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5076871/851811). [Here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Relationships#Example_of_a_map_key_join_column_relationship_annotation) is another example.

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "perm_cat_map", 
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "perm_cat_id") }, 
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id") })
@MapKeyColumn(name="permission_id")
private Map<String, Permission> permissions = new HashMap<String,Permission>(0);
```

Comment: what will be the return type of the method ? and what do you think about question 2 ?

Comment: Take into account that the return of a `select new map` HQL statement is a list of maps, one for each result, in which the keys are the aliases and the values the column values. If you want to get a map<permissionId, permissionName>, @DonRoby 's suggestion about `ResultTransformer` might be more aligned with what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Question, in your above sample, what will be the value of the string in the map ?

Comment: i will ask the second question in separate question.

Comment: @fresh_dev It is not possible to map an association to a Map<String, String>. You can use the type of one of the columns as the key. If it is a non-mapped entity, you can use `@MapKeyColumn`. If it is a mapped entity, you must use `@MapKeyJoinColumn`. The value of the String would be the `permission_id` field in the `Permission` entity.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean. In a `Map` the key can not be duplicate by nature.

Comment: when i tried the following: `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinTable(name = "perm_cat_map", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "perm_cat_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id") })
 @MapKeyJoinColumn(name = "display_name")
 private Map<String, Permission> permissions = new HashMap<String, Permission>(
   0);` i got an exception where Permission is a mapped entity.

Comment: exception is: `null index column for collection: com.myApp.PermissionCategory.permissions; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: null index column for collection: com.spring.sample.domain.PermissionCategory.permissions`

Comment: Have you tried using `@MapKeyColumn` instead of `@MapKeyJoinColumn` ?

Answer (score 26):

try like this,

```
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
String HQL_QUERY = "select new map(user.id as id, user.firstName as fullName) from User user";        
List<Map<String,String>> usersList = session.createQuery(HQL_QUERY).list();
```

Answer (score 9):

> 1- But i was wondering if it's possible to make an HQL (or native sql
>   if not possible) to select the permission_id, permission_name and
>   return them in a map.

its posible with Resulttransformer

```
String queryString="select id, name from Permission ";
List<List<Object>> permission= session.createQuery(queryString)
      .setResultTransformer(Transformers.TO_LIST).list();
//now you just expect two columns 
HashMap<Integer,String> map= new HashMap<Integer,String>();
for(List<Object> x: permission){ 
     map.put((Integer)x.get(0),(String)x.get(1))
}
```

Answer (score 5):

In JPA 2.0 (which recent versions of Hibernate support), you can map collections of primitives using an `@ElementCollection` annotation.

For some samples of such mappings see [the hibernate collections docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html).

If you're not actually mapping it in this way but want to create a map using either HQL or a Criteria query, you can create a [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) to create a map from the returned result set.

Judging from Xavi's answer, I guess there is also support in HQL for creating a map without using a transformer.

Comment: i updated my second question, can you please give me some advise.

Answer (score 5):

```
String sqlQuery="select userId,name,dob from user"
```

Pass the query to following method.

```
public List<Map<String,Object>> getDataListBySQL(final String sql, final Long adId){

    List<Map<String,Object>> list=(List<Map<String,Object>>)getHibernateTemplate().executeFind(new HibernateCallback() {
        public Object doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException,SQLException {
            Query query=session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            query.setParameter("adId", adId);               
            return query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
        }
    }); 
    return list;
}

Iterate this list in this way-
for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){

        Map<String,Object> map=list.get(i);

        System.out.println(map.get("userId"));
        System.out.println(map.get("name"));
    }
```