# Hibernate: HashMap with a List of Objects Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I got several Projects with an `ID` and a `Name`. A Project contains several Models, while each Model contains several Simulations.

I thought about saving a `HashMap` in my Project entity

```
private HashMap<Model, ArrayList<Simulation>> modelSimulation = new HashMap<>();
```

But I actually have no clue what Annotation to use.. I tried      `@CollectionOfElements` but I just got this exception:

```
Illegal attempt to map a non collection as a @OneToMany..
```

Project:

```
@Entity
public class Project {
private final IntegerProperty pID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

private HashMap<Model, ArrayList<Simulation>> modelSimulation = new HashMap<>();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getsID() {
    return pID.get();
}

@Column(name = "NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}


public HashMap<Model, ArrayList<Simulation>> getModelSimulation() {
    return modelSimulation;
}

public void setModelSimulation(
        HashMap<Model, ArrayList<Simulation>> modelSimulation) {
    this.modelSimulation = modelSimulation;
}
}
```

Simulation

```
@Entity
public class Simulation {
private final IntegerProperty sID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getsID() {
    return sID.get();
}

@Column(name = "NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name.set(name);
}
}
```

Model

```
@Entity
public class Model {
private final IntegerProperty mID = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
private final StringProperty name = new SimpleStringProperty();

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getsID() {
    return mID.get();
}

@Column(name = "NAME")
public String getName() {
    return name.get();
}
}
```

This is what I want to have as tables:

**Project**

**ID Name**

1 Project A

2 Project B

**Model**

**ID Name**

1 Model A

2 Model B

**Simulation**

**ID Name**

1 Simulation A

2 Simulation B

3 Simulation C

**IntermediateTable**

**ProjectID ModelID SimulationID**

1    --    1     --   1

1    --    2     --   2

1    --    1     --   3

Comment: I'm not sure hibernate can do That, this is not the way we use to create association. But there a some way to associate directly to a Map in a different way you try to do, see that answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876724/how-to-return-mapkey-value-with-hql

Comment: The JPA specifciation does not mandate that mappings of type Map<X, Collection<Y>>should be supported and I am not aware of any provider specific solutions. There is however some discussion here on implementing in HIbernate using some custom code: http://blog.xebia.com/2007/10/05/mapping-multimaps-with-hibernate/

Comment: While there seem to be no solution I decided to code an workaround with an helper class which holds the simulations, one project and one model.