# How to create the hibernate custom query which returns hashmap values in dao

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hashmap, dao

I want to execute custom query using hibernate in dao..
I've tried following

```
Query query = sessionFactory
            .getCurrentSession()
            .createQuery("select new map(role,count(role)) from loginDetails group by 1"); 
 List<HashMap<String,Integer> >tuples = (List<HashMap<String,Integer>>) query.list();
```

I got following result

```
 [{0=ADMIN, 1=13}, {0=COMPANY, 1=5}, {0=USER, 1=9}]
```

But  I want the result like

```
[{ADMIN, 13}, {COMPANY, 5}, {USER, 9}]
```

So I can retrieve data by key .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31521446/2173960 - does this help?

Comment: @Vineet thanks for the reply man. but i dont wanna use for loop either.