# HIBERNATE: How to convert a Criteria.list() to a "Criteria.map()"

Tags: java, hibernate

I've a method that retrieves some data from a table and return it in a `java.util.List`, I need to call that method many times so I'd like to call it just once and put all the data in a `java.util.Map`, how can I do this?

My method is actually like to:

```
private List<?> getAll(final Class objClass, final Integer parentId) {

    Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(objClass);
    if (parentId != null) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("tab.parent", parentId));
    }

    criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
    return (List<?>) criteria.list();

}
```

How can I get a `HashMap` like `HashMap<parentId,List<?>>`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per stackoverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7876724/how-to-return-mapkey-value-with-hql)

> I don't think this is possible, cause a query always returns a List:
>   http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#list()
>   or in a special case a single element.
>
> There is just no method that could return a map.
>
> So without hacks like overwriting the Session to create a special
>   Criteria which also has a map() method you can't do what you want.

Just return a list and convert it into a map.